# deploying cordova admob app Advertising Identifier checks

Tags: ios, cordova, admob

Hi what are the correct answers to apples questions according Advertising Identifier checks:
See below, I am using cordova and [this plugin](https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob). Is it the first and fourth box assuming I am just distributing an app with the cordova plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am 100% sure of this answer. Even had an app rejected because of this. Admod iOS SDK uses Apple's advertising identifier (IDFA), thus the settings you are showing are 100% correct.